# How to do Groupby Ratio calculation in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below. I need to calculate the success ratio of the `Flag` column when its value is equal to `Y`  for a orgin and destination combo.

**Input**

```
ORG DSTN    FLAG
LON SIN      Y
ADL SIN      N
SIN LON      N
LON SIN      Y
LON SIN      N
ADL SIN      Y
ADL SIN      N
SIN LON      Y
SIN LON      Y
SIN LON      Y
SIN LON      N
LON SIN      N
```

**Expected Output**

```
ORG DSTN    FLAG    Ratio
LON SIN      Y       0.5
ADL SIN      N       0.3
SIN LON      N       0.6
LON SIN      Y       0.5
LON SIN      N       0.5
ADL SIN      Y       0.3
ADL SIN      N       0.3
SIN LON      Y       0.6
SIN LON      Y       0.6
SIN LON      Y       0.6
SIN LON      N       0.6
LON SIN      N       0.5
```

How can this be done in  pandas.

Comment: why is `ADL SIN N` 0.3?? should it not be `0.6`? there are two `N` and one `Y`

Comment: @Onyambu - its 1/3 . One Y and 2  N . So its 1 divided 3

Comment: For the Y, but for N wont it be 2/3?? or it just takes 1/3??

Comment: @Onyambu,  for all Orgin and destination combination . I want the ratio be  to Y ratio's .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `value_counts` with `normalize=True`:

```
s = (df.groupby(['ORG', 'DSTN']).FLAG
        .value_counts(normalize=True).rename('Ratio').reset_index()
)
```

Then changing rows where `FLAG` equals `N` to their corresponding `Y` value, and merging:

```
s.loc[s.FLAG.eq('N'), 'Ratio'] = 1.0 - s.Ratio
df.merge(s, how='left')
```

```
   ORG DSTN FLAG     Ratio
0   LON  SIN    Y  0.500000
1   ADL  SIN    N  0.333333
2   SIN  LON    N  0.600000
3   LON  SIN    Y  0.500000
4   LON  SIN    N  0.500000
5   ADL  SIN    Y  0.333333
6   ADL  SIN    N  0.333333
7   SIN  LON    Y  0.600000
8   SIN  LON    Y  0.600000
9   SIN  LON    Y  0.600000
10  SIN  LON    N  0.600000
11  LON  SIN    N  0.500000
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can also group, then replace everything with the group proportion of `FLAG=='Y'`

```
 df.assign(Ratio=df.groupby(['ORG','DSTN']).FLAG.apply(lambda x:x.replace('Y|N',(x=='Y').mean(),regex=True)))
Out[174]: 
    ORG DSTN FLAG     Ratio
0   LON  SIN    Y  0.500000
1   ADL  SIN    N  0.333333
2   SIN  LON    N  0.600000
3   LON  SIN    Y  0.500000
4   LON  SIN    N  0.500000
5   ADL  SIN    Y  0.333333
6   ADL  SIN    N  0.333333
7   SIN  LON    Y  0.600000
8   SIN  LON    Y  0.600000
9   SIN  LON    Y  0.600000
10  SIN  LON    N  0.600000
11  LON  SIN    N  0.500000
```